# Why do I get error message upon filling Jquery datatable from c# webapi ?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-web-api, datatables

I have been using WebApi 2 with c# in webforms, to return a list of UserNames and Passwords so can be used in Jquery Datatable but it doesn't work and throws error:

**Requested unknown parameter '0' for row 0, column 0.**

Api:

```
namespace WebApiHimHer.Controllers
{
    public class UsersController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public DTResult GetData([FromUri]DTParameters v)
        {

            //List<string[]> s = new List<string[]>();

            List<basicoperations> s = new List<basicoperations>();

            basicoperations bo= new basicoperations();

            s = bo.getUsers(10, 0, 0, "asc", "");

            var jsonSerialiser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            var json = jsonSerialiser.Serialize(s);

            DTResult r = new DTResult();
            r.draw = 1;
            r.recordsFiltered = 25;
            r.recordsTotal = 25;
            r.data = s;

            return r;
        }
    }

    public class DTResult
    {
        public int draw { get; set; }
        public int recordsTotal { get; set; }
        public int recordsFiltered { get; set; }
        public List<basicoperations> data { get; set; }
    }
    public abstract class DTRow
    {
        public virtual string DT_RowId
        {
            get { return null; }
        }
        public virtual string DT_RowClass
        {
            get { return null; }
        }
        public virtual object DT_RowData
        {
            get { return null; }
        }
    }
    public class DTParameters
    {
        public int draw { get; set; }
        public DTColumn[] columns { get; set; }
        public DTOrder[] order { get; set; }
        public int start { get; set; }
        public int length { get; set; }
        public DTSearch search { get; set; }
        public string sortOrder
        {
            get
            {
                return columns != null && order != null && order.Length > 0
                    ? (columns[order[0].Column].Data + (order[0].Dir == DTOrderDir.DESC ? " " + order[0].Dir : string.Empty))
                    : null;
            }
        }
    }
    public class DTColumn
    {
        public string Data { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool Searchable { get; set; }
        public bool Orderable { get; set; }
        public DTSearch Search { get; set; }
    }
    public class DTOrder
    {
        public int Column { get; set; }
        public DTOrderDir Dir { get; set; }
    }
    public enum DTOrderDir
    {
        ASC,
        DESC
    }
    public class DTSearch
    {
        public string Value { get; set; }
        public bool Regex { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Jquery:

```
function show()
            {                               

                                $('#example').DataTable( {
//                                  "processing": true,
                                    "serverSide": true,
                                    "contentType": 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                                    "ajax": "http://localhost:28071/Users"


                                } );
            }
```

Response from Webapi:

**{"draw":1,"recordsTotal":25,"recordsFiltered":25,"data":[{"UserName":"Hunain","Password":"123"},{"UserName":"Hunain","Password":"123"},{"UserName":"ravaid","Password":"123"},{"UserName":"Waleed","Password":"123"},{"UserName":"Jim Carrey","Password":"123"},{"UserName":"da","Password":"asd"},{"UserName":"hunain","Password":"321"},{"UserName":"sd","Password":"asd"},{"UserName":"bekhudi","Password":"123"},{"UserName":"hk","Password":"asd"}]}**

Comment: you are missing columns:[] from your DatatTable() so it does not know where to put the data

Comment: @Bindrid yes pal, I did but same error

Answer (score 0):

I added the columns

```
   $('#example').DataTable({
        //                                  "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "contentType": 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        "ajax": "http://localhost:28071/Users",
        columns:[{data:"UserName"}, { data:"Password"}]

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Done,

It was because I was returning an array of objects instead of an array of strings.